# Read txt file selectively in R

Tags: r, excel, read.table

I'm looking for an easy fix to read a txt file that looks like this when opened in excel:

```
IDmaster    By_uspto    App_date    Grant_date  Applicant   Cited   
2   1   19671106    19700707    Motorola Inc    1052446 
2   1   19740909    19751028    Gen Motors Corp 1062884 
2   1   19800331    19820817    Amp Incorporated    1082369 
2   1   19910515    19940719    Dell Usa L.P.   389546  
2   1   19940210    19950912    Schueman Transfer    Inc.   1164239
2   1   19940217    19950912    Spacelabs Medical    Inc.   1164336
```

EDIT: Opening the txt file in notepad looks like this (with commas). The last two rows exhibit the problem.

```
IDmaster,By_uspto,App_date,Grant_date,Applicant,Cited
2,1,19671106,19700707,Motorola Inc,1052446
2,1,19740909,19751028,Gen Motors Corp,1062884
2,1,19800331,19820817,Amp Incorporated,1082369
2,1,19910515,19940719,Dell Usa L.P.,389546
2,1,19940210,19950912,Schueman Transfer, Inc.,1164239
2,1,19940217,19950912,Spacelabs Medical, Inc.,1164336
```

The problem is that some of the `Applicant` names contain commas so that they are read as if they belong in a different column, which they actually don't.

Is there a simple way to
a) "teach" R to keep string variables together, regardless of commas in between
b) read in the first 4 columns, and then add an extra column for everything behind the last comma?

Given the length of the data I can't open it entirely in excel which would be otherwise a simple alternative.

Comment: There is no comma in your example. If you have fixed width format, use `read.fwf` function.

Comment: That's because I copied the example from excel so all the commas are gone. As said, it's a .txt file so all the tabs actually represent commas. I uploaded the same example from the txt file as well.

Comment: It's indeed a bit similar to that question but I have no thousand separators and no problems with "" so I cannot really apply the code. Perhaps it could be tweaked to work but that would require me understanding how `gsub` works very well, which I don't ;(

Comment: If you can use `sed`, you can do something like `sed 's/,/,"/4' file.csv | sed 's/\(.*\),/\1",/' > newfile.csv` which essentially quotes everything after the 4th comma, and before the last comma and outputs to a newfile.csv. Then you can easily use `read.csv` to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your example is written in a "Test.csv" file, try with:

```
read.csv(text=gsub(', ', ' ', paste0(readLines("Test.csv"),collapse="\n")),
         quote="'",
         stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

It returns:

```
#   IDmaster By_uspto App_date Grant_date              Applicant   Cited
# 1        2        1 19671106   19700707           Motorola Inc 1052446
# 2        2        1 19740909   19751028        Gen Motors Corp 1062884
# 3        2        1 19800331   19820817       Amp Incorporated 1082369
# 4        2        1 19910515   19940719          Dell Usa L.P.  389546
# 5        2        1 19940210   19950912 Schueman Transfer Inc. 1164239
# 6        2        1 19940217   19950912 Spacelabs Medical Inc. 1164336
```

Comment: This seems to work fine and much more sensibly than my workaround :)  thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. If all your data are like this, it would be enough. But I am not sure if it will work for more complicated case.

Answer (score 1):

This provides a very silly workaround but it does the trick for me (because I don't really care about the Applicant names atm. However, I'm hoping for a better solution.

Step 1: Open the .txt file in notepad, and add five column names V1, V2, V3, V4, V5 (to be sure to capture names with multiple commas).

```
bc <- read.table("data.txt", header = T, na.strings = T, fill = T, sep = ",", stringsAsFactors = F)

library(data.table)

sapply(bc, class)
unique(bc$V5) # only NA so can be deleted
setDT(bc)
bc <- bc[,1:10, with = F]
bc$Cited <- as.numeric(bc$Cited)
  bc$Cited[is.na(bc$Cited)] <- 0
  bc$V1 <- as.numeric(bc$V1)
  bc$V2 <- as.numeric(bc$V2)
  bc$V3 <- as.numeric(bc$V3)
  bc$V4 <- as.numeric(bc$V4)

  bc$V1[is.na(bc$V1)] <- 0
  bc$V2[is.na(bc$V2)] <- 0
  bc$V3[is.na(bc$V3)] <- 0
  bc$V4[is.na(bc$V4)] <- 0

head(bc, 10)
bc$Cited <- with(bc, Cited + V1 + V2 + V3 + V4)
```

It's a silly patch but it does the trick in this particular context